# How can I add a google search command for discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I add a google search command for discord.py since it might be useful for the discord bot I'm making. Like I will do .search "name" and it will show the results on google.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from googlesearch import search
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.command
async def googlesearch(ctx,search_msg):
  for URL in search(search_msg,stop=10):
      await ctx.send(url)

client.run("YOUR_TOKEN")
```

This command just searches and displays 10 first URLs

To use it do `.googlesearch <your search>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 import discord
 from discord.ext import commands
 from googlesearch import search

 bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='<', intents=discord.Intents.all())
 @bot.command()
 async def googlesearch(ctx,search_msg):
 for URL in search(search_msg):
    url = URL
    await ctx.send(url)
```

This will show urls

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76242386/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).